# Matching third field in a CSV with pattern file in GNU Linux (AWK/SED/GREP)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to print all the lines in a CSV file when 3rd field matches a pattern in a pattern file.

I have tried grep with no luck because it matches with any field not only the third.

```
grep -f FILE2 FILE1 > OUTPUT
```

FILE1

```
dasdas,0,00567,1,lkjiou,85249
sadsad,1,52874,0,lkjiou,00567
asdasd,0,85249,1,lkjiou,52874
dasdas,1,48555,0,gfdkjh,06793
sadsad,0,98745,1,gfdkjh,45346
asdasd,1,56321,0,gfdkjh,47832
```

FILE2

```
00567
98745
45486
54543
48349
96349
56485
19615
56496
39493
```

RIGHT OUTPUT

```
dasdas,0,00567,1,lkjiou,85249
sadsad,0,98745,1,gfdkjh,45346
```

WRONG OUTPUT

```
dasdas,0,00567,1,lkjiou,85249
sadsad,1,52874,0,lkjiou,00567   <---- I don't want this to appear
sadsad,0,98745,1,gfdkjh,45346
```

I have already searched everywhere and tried different formulas.

EDIT: thanks to Wintermute, I managed to write something like this:

```
csvquote file1.csv > file1.csv
awk -F '"' 'FNR == NR { patterns[$0] = 1; next } patterns[$6]' file2.csv file1.csv | csvquote -u > result.csv
```

Csvquote helps parsing CSV files with AWK.

Thank you very much everybody, great community!

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { patterns[$0] = 1; next } patterns[$3]' file2 file1
```

This works as follows:

```
FNR == NR {           # when processing the first file (the pattern file)
  patterns[$0] = 1    # remember the patterns
  next                # and do nothing else
}
patterns[$3]          # after that, select lines whose third field
                      # has been seen in the patterns.
```

Comment: Nice answer. You could reduce it to `awk -F, '{a[$0]++}a[$3]' file2 file`

Comment: @JID That would probably work, but I don't like adding new entries to the pattern array when processing the second file (which does not contain patterns) even if it is unlikely that they'll be matched. If that file contains a line without commas, you could get wrong results. Corner case? Yes. But there's no reason to run the risk.

Comment: given OP's data i didn't think that would be a problem but fair enough :) You could still remove the `next` though i think unless there are comma separated fields in file2. I'm just being picky though because i don't like `next`.

Comment: Is the first file can be a pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` and `sed`:

```
grep -f <( sed -e 's/^\|$/,/g' file2) file1
dasdas,0,00567,1,lkjiou,85249
sadsad,0,98745,1,gfdkjh,45346
```

Explanation:

We insert a coma at the beginning and at the end of file2, but without changing the file, then we just grep as you were already doing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a start

for i in $(cat FILE2);do cat FILE1| cut -d',' -f3|grep $i ;done

Comment: are you sure it print the whole line of file 1 if selected ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#.*#/^[^,]*,[^,]*,&,/!d#' File2 >/tmp/File2.sed && sed -f /tmp/File2.sed FILE1;rm /tmp/File2.sed
```

hard in a simple sed like awk can do but should work if awk is not available

same with egrep (usefull on huge file)

```
sed 's#.*#^[^,]*,[^,]*,&,#' File2 >/tmp/File2.egrep && egrep -f /tmp/File2.egrep FILE1;rm /tmp/File2.egrep
```