# Select rows in a CSV not matching any pattern in pattern file in GNU Linux (AWK/SED/GREP)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to print all the lines in a CSV file when 3rd field does not matches a pattern in a pattern file. I've been doing the opposite, printing matches with the following script:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { patterns[$0] = 1; next } patterns[$3]' FILE2 FILE1
```

FILE1

```
dasdas,0,00567,1,lkjiou,85249
sadsad,1,52874,0,lkjiou,00567
asdasd,0,85249,1,lkjiou,52874
dasdas,1,48555,0,gfdkjh,06793
sadsad,0,98745,1,gfdkjh,45346
asdasd,1,56321,0,gfdkjh,47832
```

FILE2

```
00567
98745
45486
54543
48349
96349
56485
19615
56496
39493
```

OUTPUT

```
dasdas,0,00567,1,lkjiou,85249
sadsad,0,98745,1,gfdkjh,45346
```

How can I print lines not matching patterns in pattern file?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do not use the word "pattern" as it is highly ambiguous. Are you looking to match on a number, a string or a regexp? Are you looking for a full or partial match?

Answer (score 1):

Invert the selection:

```
#                                             v-- here
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { patterns[$0] = 1; next } !patterns[$3]' FILE2 FILE1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need invert the match from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318219/matching-third-field-in-a-csv-with-pattern-file-in-gnu-linux-awk-sed-grep)

```
grep -vf <( sed -e 's/^\|$/,/g' file2) file1
```

PS. see the `-v` flag